# Visual Studio Tools for Applications - Compiler information

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, c#-2.0, infopath2010, vsta

- I am currently using VSTA 2005 for InfoPath form code behind.
- I am using InfoPath forms 2007.
- The compiler for VSTA 2005 is C# 2.0.

My question is, has anyone had any experience with resolving the archaic compiler issue?

Answer (score 0):

I will keep this short and sweet. If at all possible download and install  the following:

- Visual Studio 2012
- [Microsoft's Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38806)
- [Microsoft's Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38807)
- Office 2013

Currently I have found no issue with moving a 2007 InfoPath form with code behind up to InfoPath 2013. The code behind association will remain but now your IDE will be up to date.

**Disclaimer:**
Abandon all hope if you install Office 2013 on a SharePoint 2010 box. The assemblies will conflict and at the time of writing this answer, still no work around besides moving to SharePoint 2013.